# ASP.NET: Convert date values back and forth when reading/inserting into database

Tags: asp.net, sql, date

I have a AsyncFileupload control on .aspx page where I am uploading an image. I am extracting very basic file information such as date created/accessed.

For every single file, the code gives me one static value that is

```
01/01/1601 00:00:00
```

Which obviously cannot be right. I am sure that there is a conversion is done automatically behind.

How can I convert it into actual value AND convert it back into CYYMMDD format (i want this particular format in bd)?
Thanks

on `UploadedComplete` i run this code

```
 string savePath = MapPath("~/" + Path.GetFileName(e.FileName));

 FileInfo MyFileInfo = new FileInfo(savePath);

 txt_Textbox1.Text = MyFileInfo.CreationTime.ToString();
```

this always gives me following output, regardless the actual date is today's date

```
01/01/1601 00:00:00
```

How can i convert it into its original creation date?

Comment: Can you please provide us with your research done till now.

Comment: code added, hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `MyFileInfo.Exists` is `true` before you use other properties of FileInfo variable.

I'm sure in your case the `MyFileInfo.Exists` is `false`. That's the reason you'll get those values for the properties like `CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime` etc.